# Get the value from the select tag in html, i know this will show that is possibly duplicate but please take a look

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get the value from the selector tag in html and pass it to another function which is called myFunction. But the error says that it is null.

```js
< script >
  (function() {
    var selector = document.getElementById("carSelector");
    var value = selector[selector.selectedIndex].value;
    console.log(value);
    document.getElementById('carsButton').onclick = function() {
      myFunction(value);
    };
  }()); 
</script>
```

```html
<div class="selectList">
  <select name="cars" id="carSelector">
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="Kia">Kia</option>
  </select>
  <button id="carsButton" type="button">Show car</button>
</div>
```

The code should get the car type from the selector and pass it to the function myFunction.

Comment: You're targeting `carButton` but your element ID is `carsButton`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just get the `value` of the `<select>` - it'll be the `value` of the selected option:

```js
function show() {
  var select = document.getElementById("carSelector");
  var value = select.value;
  console.log(value);
}
```

```html
<select name="cars" id="carSelector">
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="Kia">Kia</option>
</select>
<button id="carsButton" type="button" onclick="show()">Show car</button>
```

Comment: No problem @SachihiroTakamori, always glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Slight typo (id should be carsButton)  and I rearranged the code a little - you were expecting a named function - but not providing one.

You don't really need the named function - you could just log the selected value to the console within the onclick handler - but so that you can practise passing values between function - I left it in.

Also - you only need "(function() {}) if you are using jQuery - oits not needed for this - but again - I left it in - in case you needed it for something else.

```js
(function() {
  
    document.getElementById('carsButton').onclick = function() {
      var selector = document.getElementById("carSelector");
      var value = selector.value;
      myFunction(value);
    };
    
    
    function  myFunction(value) {
      console.log(value);
     }
    
    
  }());
```

```html
<div class="selectList">
  <select name="cars" id="carSelector">
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="Kia">Kia</option>
  </select>
  <button id="carsButton" type="button">Show car</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but for my use, it seems unnecessary complicated. I copied from developer.mozilla and i dont fully understand so, i think is better to use the code below which is simpler for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

you probably meant to get the item from `selector.options`, `selector` won't have anything at `selector.selectedIndex` it will be `undefined`

```
var value = selector.options[selector.selectedIndex].value;
```